# How to search for and perform calculations with groups with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column B_S with two values "S2" and "S1". S2 marks the boundary of each group and the original row for each group. S1 marks the possible items that need to be checked in terms of High column.

For example, I need to check if S1 High is greater than S2 High. I need to cycle through all the S1 entries and choose the row where S1 High is higher than S2 High and remove the rows where S1 High is not higher than S2.

I am not experienced enough with data.table to produce such as result.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
structure(list(Time = c("16/10/2014 09:19", "16/10/2014 09:20", 
"16/10/2014 09:21", "16/10/2014 09:22", "17/12/2014 12:59", "17/12/2014   13:00", 
    "17/12/2014 13:01", "17/12/2014 13:02"), High = c(1833.5, 1832.5, 
1820.5, 1852.5, 1992, 1991.25, 2001.25, 2002.25), rn = c(77470L, 
77469L, 77468L, 77467L, 17758L, 17757L, 17756L, 17755L), B_S = c("S2", 
"S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S1", "S1", "S1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
```

Expected results:
For the 1st group (rows 1-4), row 1 and row 4 would be retained.

```
 structure(list(Time = c("16/10/2014 09:19", "16/10/2014 09:22"
), High = c(1833.5, 1852.5), rn = c(77470L, 77467L), B_S = c("S2", 
"S1")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)
```

For the second group (rows 5-8) row 5 and row 7 would be retained.

```
    structure(list(Time = c("17/12/2014 12:59", "17/12/2014 13:01"
), High = c(1992, 2001.25), rn = c(17758L, 17756L), B_S = c("S2", 
"S1")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)
```

Answer (score 3):

An option would be group by cumulative sum of logical condition where 'B_S' is 'S2', then get the index of 'High' greater than or equal to the `first` value of 'High', select the first two positions, extract the row index (`.I`) and subset the rows based on that

```
i1 <- df1[,  .I[which((High >= first(High)))[1:2]], .(grp = cumsum(B_S == "S2"))]$V1
df1[i1]
#               Time    High    rn B_S
#1: 16/10/2014 09:19 1833.50 77470  S2
#2: 16/10/2014 09:22 1852.50 77467  S1
#3: 17/12/2014 12:59 1992.00 17758  S2
#4: 17/12/2014 13:01 2001.25 17756  S1
```